# Calculating a polynomial's coefficients from its roots

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, polynomials

Let $P$ be a monic polynomial polynomial given by its roots:
$$P(X) = (X-x_1)\times...\times(X-x_n)$$

What is the minimum asymptotic complexity to compute its expansion of the form:
$$a_nX^n+...+a_0$$

---

What I have found so far are [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) which give an expression of each $a_k$ as a sum over $1\leq i_1 < ... < i_{n-k} \leq n$. This would suggest the complexity of computing the $k$th coefficient is something like ${n-1 \choose n-k-1}={n-1 \choose k}=O(n^k)$, thus making the total complexity bonkers (I guess something like $O(n^n)$).

Yet my teacher's presentation suggests it is a $O(n^2)$, which doesn't match my calculation at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every integer $i$, $0\le i\le n$, let 
$$P_i(X) = (X-x_1)(X-x_2)\cdots(X-x_i)=a_{i,i}X^i+a_{i,i-1}X^{i-1}+\cdots+...+a_{i,0}$$
for some $a_{i,k}$, $0\le k\le i$. In particular, $a_{i,i}=1$. Expanding $P$ on both sides of the following equation and comparing the coefficients, 
$$P_{i+1}(X) = P_i(X)(X-x_{i+1})$$
we see that for $1\le k\le i\lt n$, 
$$a_{i+1,k}=-a_{i,k}x_{i+1}+a_{i,k-1}$$
and
$$a_{i+1,0} = -a_{i,0}x_{i+1}$$
So for fixed $i$, we can compute all coefficients of $P_{i+1}(X)$ from the coefficients of $P_i(X)$ with $O(i)$ steps. Now you should be able to see that your professor's suggestion on the minimum asymptotic complexity makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured out another way of seeing whilst reading your answer: one can calculate $\sigma_{k+1}$ in $n$ operations from $\sigma_k$ (multiply by each root and sum) and thus apply Vieta's formulas in $O(n^2)$ time.

Comment: @JohnDo, I do not think I understand "another way" of yours. How do you get, for example, from $x_1+x_2$ to $x_1x_2$? Or from $x_1+x_2+x3$ to $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$?

Comment: Nevermind, I was actually wrong, I was imagining something like $(x_1+x_2)\times x_1 + (x_1+x_2)\times x_2$, which doesn't work...